# Capturing FnMut closure doesn't live long enough

Tags: rust, callback, closures, lifetime, fn

### Problem

In short: I'm trying to implement an `struct` that contains a callback to an closure, which captures state mutably. Idea is that user provides callback (closure) and can be informed later when a specific event happens.

I have a working proof-of-concept version (**code sample #1**).

### This PoC works ([code sample #1](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd2ca32fe7a831b040f3b5aef02e70a3)):

```rust
fn fun<F>(f: F) -> F
    where
        F: FnMut() -> (),
{
    f
}

fn main() {
    let mut abc = "abc".to_string();
    let mut f = fun(|| {
        abc.push_str(".");
        println!("closure: {:?}", abc);
    });
    f();
    f();
    f();
    println!("end: {:?}", abc);
}
```

Output:

```
closure: "abc."
closure: "abc.."
closure: "abc..."
end: "abc..."
```

### This fails ([code sample #2](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dbd96bded2ceb81406785577eeba7683)):

Same idea (slightly different) as previous but trying to contain closure inside `Foo`.

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    pub cb: Box<dyn FnMut(&T) + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> {
    fn new(f: impl FnMut(&T) + 'a) -> Self {
        Self { cb: Box::new(f) }
    }
    fn on_change(&mut self, f: impl FnMut(&T) + 'a)
    {
        self.cb = Box::new(f);
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Default for Foo<'a, T>
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(|_| {})
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut abc = "abc".to_string();
    let mut f = Foo::default();
    f.on_change(|a| {
        abc.push_str("."); // PROBLEM HERE; uncomment and it works!
        println!("- param: {:?}", a);
    });
    let param = "a".to_string();
    (f.cb)(&param);
    (f.cb)(&param);
    (f.cb)(&param);
    println!("end: {:?}", abc);
}
```

Expected output:

```
- param: "a"
- param: "a"
- param: "a"
end: "abc..."
```

Actual output (compiler error):

```rust
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `abc` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:33:27
   |
25 |     f.on_change(|a| {
   |                 --- mutable borrow occurs here
26 |         abc.push_str("."); // PROBLEM HERE; uncomment and it works!
   |         --- first borrow occurs due to use of `abc` in closure
...
33 |     println!("end: {:?}", abc);
   |                           ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
34 | }
   | - mutable borrow might be used here, when `f` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Foo<'_, String>`
```

The compiler error is pretty clear and it definitely has something to do with lifetimes. I think my problem is that I need to tell the compiler about the closure and its parameter lifetimes – but the question is, how?

How should I modify **code sample #2** to get callback registration work like in **code sample #1**?

REPL:

- [code sample #1](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd2ca32fe7a831b040f3b5aef02e70a3)
- [code sample #2](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dbd96bded2ceb81406785577eeba7683)

Comment: You just need to release the borrow on `abc` contained in `f` for example with `drop(f);` before trying to access `abc` again.

Comment: So basically there are 3 approaches to the problem: 1.) call `drop` 2.) use `{`, `}` for lifetime 3.) Wrap `abc`in `Rc<T>`?

Comment: Maybe? 4.) return closure object from `on_call` to stack and control lifetime through a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abc` is still bound in `f`.

Variables get destroyed at the end of the scope they live in. `f` lives in `main`, so `f` gets destroyed at the end of main, which means that during the `println`, `f` still lives and binds `abc`.

To destroy a variable earlier, you have to possibilities:

- call `drop` on it
- put it in a nested scope

Here with `drop`:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    pub cb: Box<dyn FnMut(&T) + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> {
    fn new(f: impl FnMut(&T) + 'a) -> Self {
        Self { cb: Box::new(f) }
    }
    fn on_change(&mut self, f: impl FnMut(&T) + 'a) {
        self.cb = Box::new(f);
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Default for Foo<'a, T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(|_| {})
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut abc = "abc".to_string();
    let mut f = Foo::default();
    f.on_change(|a| {
        abc.push_str("."); // PROBLEM HERE; uncomment and it works!
        println!("- param: {:?}", a);
    });
    let param = "a".to_string();
    (f.cb)(&param);
    (f.cb)(&param);
    (f.cb)(&param);

    drop(f);

    println!("end: {:?}", abc);
}
```

And here with a nested scope:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    pub cb: Box<dyn FnMut(&T) + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> {
    fn new(f: impl FnMut(&T) + 'a) -> Self {
        Self { cb: Box::new(f) }
    }
    fn on_change(&mut self, f: impl FnMut(&T) + 'a) {
        self.cb = Box::new(f);
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Default for Foo<'a, T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(|_| {})
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut abc = "abc".to_string();

    {
        let mut f = Foo::default();
        f.on_change(|a| {
            abc.push_str("."); // PROBLEM HERE; uncomment and it works!
            println!("- param: {:?}", a);
        });
        let param = "a".to_string();
        (f.cb)(&param);
        (f.cb)(&param);
        (f.cb)(&param);
    }

    println!("end: {:?}", abc);
}
```

Both code snippets print:

```
- param: "a"
- param: "a"
- param: "a"
end: "abc..."
```

Comment: In your code the caller is responsible for the lifetime, which isn't optimal. I guess what I'm trying to achieve here might be impossible. Optimal solution would be: `Foo` would be responsible for lifetime, but it can't be, because captured reference lifetime is unknown from `Foo`s perspective. Unless there is some other approach I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Osteri A lifetime is not a runtime mechanism, it's a compiler check. You can use `Rc<RefCell>` or `Arc<Mutex>` for runtime lifetime checks.